# Placing PHP data pulled from an API into a HTML table

Tags: php, api, html-table

I'm new to APIs and PHP but for an assignment at university I'm having to pull data from an API and display it. I currently have the following code working but I can't figure out how to make it display each Pokemon name separately in a table so that I can add images and other data into each cell with it:

```
 <?php  
        $base = "http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/";
        for($id = 1; $id < 13; $id++){
            $data = file_get_contents($base.$id.'/');
            $pokemon = json_decode($data);
            echo $pokemon->name."<br>";
        }
    ?>
```

Any takers? I know it's probably an easy fix, I'm just so new to this and everything I try breaks the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using an html table?

```
<?php
  $base = "http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/";
?>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Picture</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php
    for($id = 1; $id < 13; $id++){
      $data = file_get_contents($base.$id.'/');
      $pokemon = json_decode($data);
      echo '<tr>
        <td>
          <img src="'. $pokemon->sprites->front_default .'" width="30px" />
        </td>
        <td>
          '. $pokemon->name .'
        </td>
      </tr>';
    }
  ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you so much! you absolutely answered my question perfectly, if not more than required!